# Is there a way to have Routify ignore certain URL paths?

Tags: go, single-page-application, svelte, buffalo, routify

We're using Go (Buffalo) to serve up both an API and the static assets for a Single-Page Application (SPA) that uses Svelte and Routify.

However, I'd like to have certain routes (e.g. "/auth/login") be ignored by Routify and instead go to the Go / Buffalo server, for handling those requests.

Is there a Routify setting for that?

I see the [`ignore` build config](https://www.routify.dev/docs/config/build), but that seems to be for telling Routify to ignore certain files when building the list of routes, not ignoring certain URL paths.

(If I have to, I might be able to get our `/auth/login` call to work as an XHR call, then actually manually redirect the browser based on the response, but it would be nicer/simpler to simply allow the browser to go to `/auth/login` directly.)

---

**UPDATE:** Apparently going to `/auth/login` directly (e.g. in a new tab) does what I want. It's just clicking a link in the SPA that gets intercepted by Routify. So my question still stands, though slightly altered:

Is there a way to tell Routify not to intercept links to certain URL paths, but to simply let the browser go to that URL (leaving the SPA)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `target` attribute on a link tag does what I was after. Hooray for finding the appropriate documentation!

> If you want to use anchor's default navigation behaviour you can do so by adding the `target` attribute.
>
> Routify will ignore all anchors with `target` attribute.

Source:
https://www.routify.dev/guide/navigation

So in my case, I needed to do this:

```
<a href="/auth/login" target="_self">Login</a>
```